# Livecode Responsive UI Android App

Tags: android, user-interface, responsive-design, livecode

In our world today, there are lot of android devices with different screen sizes. There are big (tablet) and small (phone).
How can I make my UI in livecode app responsive so that my app fits in all screen sizes?

---

ADDITIONAL:
I tried ticking the `Live Resizing` check box but it doesn't work. Maybe I missed something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that you have a card with one field and one button. When you open the stack, you can set the `rect` of the stack to the `screenRect`. This triggers the resizeStack message, which lets you rearrange the controls on the card.

```
on preOpenCard
  set the rect of this stack to the screenRect
  pass preOpenCard
end preOpenCard

on resizeStack
  lock screen
  put the rect of this cd into myRect
  subtract 64 from item 4 of myRect
  set the rect of fld 1 to myRect
  set the loc of btn 1 to the bottom of fld 1 + 32,item 2 of the loc of this cd
  set the right of btn 1 to the width of this cd - 16
  unlock screen
end resizeStack
```

Additionally, you can set the `fullScreenMode` property of the stack to e.g `"exactFit"`. You have to do this in the `preOpenStack` handler (or in the `startUp` handler). This will resize the stack and you won't need to use the `resizeStack` handler, but all control will look slightly malformed of the aspect ration of the screen is different from the aspect ratio of the screen of the device the stack was created on.

Comment: If I have a lot of objects in the card, I need to re-size everything and that I can write a lot of scripts. Also, it is difficult to re-size the text (font size) to fit it in the size of a label.
My best way is to write these scripts `set the fullScreenMode of this stack to "exactFit"` to `preOpenStack` handler and it works even though it looks like it has been stretched. I have nothing to be worry about it because there is no android device with very short width and very long height or very short height and very long width screen size.